# executables = executables python error (trying to turn pygame into executable with cx_freeze)

Tags: pygame, executable, cx-freeze

I am trying to turn my pygame `accident.py` which works fine into an executable.

After installing `cx_freeze` and setting up the files in my `python27` directory, I run `python setup.py build` to create the executable.

I keep getting an error, perhaps I am still missing some files? my code is wrong?
Please help!

This is a screenshot of my code and what happens: http://snag.gy/In8bz.jpg

Comment: It's a bit different, but you might want to look into my tool [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I wrote it to get around the biggest problems with cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to make a pygame file into a .exe type of executable. I'm not familiar with the method you are trying to use, but check this out: http://py2exe.org/  I use it to make my games into executable files that can be downloaded by others and run without needing to install the Python API.

Hopefully this helps,
David

Comment: Hi David, I tried using the py2exe which is similar to cx_freeze, however both had a similar error while packaging my code.